# How is idle time calculated on TF tensorboard

Tags: python, tensorflow, gpu, profiling, tensorboard

I'm new to TF tensorboard. Could you please tell me how GPU idle time is calculated? I see contradictory data in profiling information on tensorboard:

- I have no blank spaces in events trace (GPU compute stream) presented on `trace_viewer` page.
- Wherein device (GPU) idle time shown on `tensorflow_stats` page is about 50%???

It's what I see when I use small batch size. After increasing batch size, same situation is on `trace_viewer` page, but GPU idle time decreased up to 7%. So, how is idle time calculated?

By the way, another two questions:

1. What is `steps` on `trace_viewer` page?
2. Why does `trace_viewer` page contain only a part of profiling time? I profiled about 100 seconds of execution, but I see only 10 seconds on `trace_viewer` page.

Thanks a lot in advance!